# Why i can't get data product_option_id by API on BigCommerce

Tags: c#, bigcommerce

I created a product with optionsetID success. And after, I create ProductSkus for it, I see options: `{"product_option_id": int, "option_value_id":int}`. What is `product_option_id`? How can I get it by API?

Answer (score 1):

[Developer portal resource page for product options](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/options)

For listing all product option IDs using basic auth: `GET /api/v2/products/{product_id}/options`

For listing all product option IDs using OAuth: `GET /stores/{store_hash}/v2/products/{product_id}/options`

Specific product option ID basic auth: `GET /api/v2/products/{product_id}/options/{id}`

Specific product option ID OAuth: `GET /stores/{store_hash}/v2/products/{product_id}/options/{id}`